# R Error in hist.default(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris) : 'x' must be numeric

Tags: r, histogram, lattice

I am trying to plot 2 histograms of a numeric variable by a factor variable in my df.

I searched hist() to do this but why am I getting this error?

```
data(iris)
hist(Sepal.Length~Species,data=iris)
Error in hist.default(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris) : 
  'x' must be numeric
```

UPDATE: I am able to get this to work:

```
histogram(~Sepal.Length|Species,data=iris,
          type="count",
          xlab="Sepal Length",
          main="Iris Dataset",
          layout=c(1,3))
```

It seems there might be a difference between histogram functions?
https://www.rforge.net/doc/packages/FSA/hist.formula.html
and
http://127.0.0.1:27473/library/lattice/html/histogram.html

Comment: `hist()` is different than `histogram()`; they are completely unrelated. The former is a base function in R and does not use the formula syntax. It looks like the `FSA` package that you linked has a hist.formula function, but `histogram` is from the Lattice package (usually, packages can define functions with the same names as functions from other packages -- no one "owns" a function name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
library(FSA)
hist(Sepal.Length~Species,data=iris)
```

It works

Comment: Install the FSA package before hand

Comment: I am using a work computer and had trouble installing directly to the default path. I had to use .libpaths() first to get the .gz to install in a different folder first.